# Finding only changed attribute from nested JSON

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am struggling this problem in long time.So here problem is I need to create new josn from the input json using NIFI internal processor.PFB the expected output.

```
input json :
[{
  "type" : "update",
  "database" : "ABC",
  "table_name" : "EXT",
  "table_id" : 78,
  "columns" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "ID",
    "column_type" : 12,
    "last_value" : "9",
    "value" : "9"
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "TRS",
    "column_type" : 12,
    "last_value" : "EWE",
    "value" : "FRD"
  },"id" : 3,
    "name" : "NM_CONT",
    "column_type" : 12,
    "last_value" : "0",
    "value" : "0"
  } ]
```

Expected output :

```
{
  "type" : "update",
  "database" : "ABC",
  "table_name" : "EXT",
  "table_id" : 78,
  "TRS": FRD
}
```

here columns isa list value, and I need to get only name and value if last_value and value is not same.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: as of now ,i have tried with queryRecord    
SQL :

SELECT
type,
"timestamp",
binlog_filename,
binlog_position,
"database",
"table_name",
from FLOWFILE WHERE RPATH(columns,'/last_value') <> RPATH(columns,'/value')

Answer (score 0):

@San

Try this:

Input -> EvaluateJsonPath (extract the values you want here) -> AttributesToJson (send chosen attributes to content of flowfile) -> Output

This is the simplest form for parsing Json from the input content.

Comment: Thank for your response , but here I have one condition actually, I need to check last_value and value(root->coloumns->[last_value, value]) column is different or not .if this is not same I need to extract the name of that index and value. you can check the expected output json

Comment: Yah I noticed it was a weird filter requirement with the columns/value.  You may need to add in SplitJson to get the columns out to separate flowfiles then ExtractJson for values, and then further process those values downstream according to your logic.    Given all the values you want parsed to attributes, you can then use nifi expression language to complete the logic in UpdateAttribute and finally send to AttributesToJson

Comment: ok, but we need to write more processor, and it will take more  time to process if we do in JOLT, could you please let me know